# ADL in noexcept, who's wrong, who's right?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, noexcept

Look [at this example on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/TSzgjr):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct A {
  template <typename U>
  void test(U&& u) noexcept(noexcept(inner_test(std::forward<U>(u)))) {
    inner_test(std::forward<U>(u));
  }

 private:
  template <typename U>
  void inner_test(U&&) noexcept(
      std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<std::decay_t<U>> &&
      std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<std::decay_t<U>>
      /* and whatever */) {
    // ...
  }
};

int main() {
    A<int> a;
    a.test(3u);
}
```

There is a class template and two function templates. The public function is just a wrapper for the private one, which has a complex noexcept specification.

I would like to let the compiler deduce the noexcept specification for the public function, in order to avoid *noexcept* code duplication (it is already awful when written once...).

Clang and MSVC seem to like the code, but GCC rejects it with the following error:

`<source>:7:48: error: 'inner_test' was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]`

Who is wrong and who is right?

Funny thing: inside noexcept(...), if you change from "&&" to "and", MSVC does not compile anymore...

The *c++17* tag is mainly because I am using a couple of "_v" that are not available in c++14.

Comment: There's no ADL in this example, for what it's worth.

Comment: @Barry I was unsure because in this case there there are instantiation of templates. I used ADL as term because it is exactly what GCC tells in its error. However, thank you.

Comment: "I used ADL as term because it is exactly what GCC tells in its error" ... I do not see where you pasted the GCC error message in the question.  That may be relevant or helpful.

Comment: @Eljay you are right. I added the error in the question.

Comment: @dodomorandi Yeah, that's unfortunate - it's a consequence of the gcc bug described in the linked question that it gives a bad error message.